# Take specific string part of string by specific requirments

Tags: vb.net

I am developing function which would give me the right side of specific string. Function has possibility to take the return string based on splitted char, keep char in string and also which is most important to say either return string will be after last occurence of that char separator or say after exactly which positon of separator occerence in string, return string after to take. Can anyone take a look on that and confirm is it right way to go or whether that code contains any issues?

Keep in mind to use as lastindex i set lastindexof to true and doesn't matter what splitterCharPosition is and vice versa when false splitterCharPosition  has to be set.

This is my current code to be confirmed:

```
 Public Function GetRightSideStringByCHar(splitterChar As String, searchingWord As String, keepCharAsWell As Boolean, lastindexof As Boolean, splitterCharPosition As Integer) As String
        Dim index As Integer
        Select Case lastindexof
            Case False
                index = GetNthIndex(searchingWord, splitterChar, splitterCharPosition)
            Case True
                index = searchingWord.LastIndexOf(splitterChar)
        End Select

        If index > 0 Then
            If keepCharAsWell Then
                searchingWord = searchingWord.Substring(0, index + splitterChar.Length)
            Else
                searchingWord = searchingWord.Substring(0, index)
            End If
        Else
            searchingWord = String.Empty
        End If
        Return searchingWord
    End Function
```

Helper function to get n index:

```
 Public Function GetNthIndex(searchingWord As String, charseparator As Char, n As Integer) As Integer
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To searchingWord.Length - 1
            If searchingWord(i) = charseparator Then
                count += 1
                If count = n Then
                    Return i
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Return -1
    End Function
```

Comment: And what exactly is your issue here ? Did you run this piece of code ? Does it work ? If you're asking for a review then you can try to ask this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your other deleted question, I formulated this for you.

It worked with all your previous examples.

```
[parameters]
str = input string
strtofind = separator string
occurance = zero-based index to start cutting (optional)
keepstringtofind = append separator to string (optional)
righttoleft = operational direction (optional)

    Public Function CutFromString(str As String, strtofind As String, Optional occurance As Integer = 0, Optional keepstrtofind As Boolean = False, Optional righttoleft As Boolean = False) As String
    Dim s As String = str
    Dim sections As List(Of String) = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(str), New List(Of String), str.Split(strtofind.ToCharArray).ToList)
    If sections.Count = 1 AndAlso sections.First = str Then sections.Clear()
    If occurance < sections.Count Then
        Dim b = sections.Count - occurance
        While b > 0
            If righttoleft Then
                sections.RemoveAt(0)
            Else
                sections.RemoveAt(sections.Count - 1)
            End If
            b -= 1
        End While
        s = Join(sections.ToArray, strtofind)
        If keepstrtofind And occurance > 0 Then
            If righttoleft Then
                s = strtofind + s
            Else
                s += strtofind
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Return s
End Function
```

Comment: seems not working for all cases. for this example:  Console.WriteLine(CutFromString("1 34.1t0#$1.trweL24w222", ".", 1, True, True))   still not dot at beggining i marked to keep or this example: CutFromString("14.1001.2", ".", 1, True, True) shoud be: 14.1001. i get: 2

Comment: Fixed a few bugs, try this version