# Extract right side of string specify by separator

Tags: vb.net

This is my code to get right side of string specifying char separator and either to keep separator within string or not. Possibility also to specify if just last occurence of char separator or manually define it. My question is how to make same version but this time to get right side of string instead of left?

```
Public Shared Function GetLetSideStringByChar(splitterChar As String, searchingWord As String, keepCharAsWell As Boolean, lastindexof As Boolean, splitterCharPosition As Integer) As String
        Dim index As Integer
        Select Case lastindexof
            Case False
                index = GetNthIndex(searchingWord, splitterChar, splitterCharPosition)
            Case True
                index = searchingWord.LastIndexOf(splitterChar)
        End Select

        If index > 0 Then
            If keepCharAsWell Then
                searchingWord = searchingWord.Substring(0, index + splitterChar.Length)
            Else
                searchingWord = searchingWord.Substring(0, index)
            End If
        Else
            searchingWord = String.Empty
        End If
        Return searchingWord
    End Function

    'jesli n separator nie odnalzeiony bedzie return -1, np jesli charseparator = . i damy n = 2 a word bedzie mial tlko jedna . to -1
    Public Shared Function GetNthIndex(searchingWord As String, charseparator As Char, n As Integer) As Integer
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To searchingWord.Length - 1
            If searchingWord(i) = charseparator Then
                count += 1
                If count = n Then
                    Return i
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Return -1
    End Function
```

Comment: Despite this functions are a complex way to not use `string.Split`, what have you already tried ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take specific string part of string by specific requirments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44240579/take-specific-string-part-of-string-by-specific-requirments)

Comment: searchingWord.Substring(index)  ?  also, you could use IndexOf instead of looping all characters.

Answer (score 0):

I had written a code for your previous problem that you deleted.
To make the code more understandable I used an Enum to specify right or left:

```
Public Enum Direction
    Left = 0
    Right = 1
End Enum
```

then you can call the function like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(StringExtract("5345.342.323.323#$%", Direction.Right, 2, False))
```

Here the Seperator Index represents the dot number (starting at 1)

**For Example:**

> 648674.2327.12 first dot is **1** second is **2**

And here is the function, I'm sure it could be shortened:

```
Public Function StringExtract(ByVal MyStr As String, ByVal Side As Direction, ByVal SeperatorIndex As Integer, ByVal SeperatorKeep As Boolean) As String
    Dim MySubs() As String = MyStr.Split(".".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim IndexOfSplit As Integer
    Dim MyResult As String = ""
    If Side = Direction.Left Then
        IndexOfSplit = SeperatorIndex - 1
        For i As Integer = IndexOfSplit To 0 Step -1
            MyResult = MyResult.Insert(0, MySubs(i) & ".")
        Next
        If SeperatorKeep = False Then
            MyResult = MyResult.Remove(MyResult.LastIndexOf("."), 1)
        End If
    Else
        IndexOfSplit = SeperatorIndex
        For i As Integer = IndexOfSplit To MySubs.Length - 1
            MyResult = MyResult & MySubs(i) & "."
        Next
        If SeperatorKeep = False Then
            MyResult = MyResult.Remove(MyResult.LastIndexOf("."), 1)
        Else
            MyResult = "." & MyResult.Remove(MyResult.LastIndexOf("."), 1)
        End If
    End If
    Return MyResult
End Function
```

**Output example:**

**Input 1:**

```
StringExtract("5345.342.323.323#$%", Direction.Right, 2, False)
```

**Output 1:**

> 323.323#$%

**Input 2:**

```
StringExtract("5345.342.323.323#$%", Direction.Right, 3, True)
```

**Output 2:**

> .323#$%

**Input 3:**

StringExtract("4.34!2.3323.", Direction.Left, 2, True)

**Output 3:**

> 4.34!2.

**PS:** If anyone has any suggestions to shorten the function let me know I'm happy to learn.